# Google Apps Script: how to use data in a spreadsheet to query a external database?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oracle-adf

I want to build an app that use data in a selected row in my google spreadsheet to make a query in an external site whose source code is something like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html dir="ltr">
    <head><title>NAME_SITE</title><meta name="name" content="Oracle ADF Faces"><link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" type="text/css" href="/name_query/adf/styles/cache/mycompany-desktop-10_1_3_4_0-webkit.css"><script>var _AdfWindowOpenError='Pop error message.';</script><script src="/name_query/adf/jsLibs/Common10_1_3_4_0.js"></script><script>_defaultTZ()</script>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
            content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
          <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/functions.js"></script>
    </head>
```

My goal is to automate the task of having to visit an external site and put the search term in it. I would simply use a function to do the query and show to user the page with the result of the query. Can I do this with GAS? What are the first steps?

Comment: Usually the onclick of the search will do POST request to a server. If you have information of how this is implemented, you can use Google Apps Script's UrlFetchApp to mimic the POST requests.

Comment: How can I get this information of how the onclick of the search do the POST request?

Comment: The owner of the site should be able to give you this. You can figure out some basic stuff from the HTML source

Answer (score 0):

You question is too vague to answer properly. Your HTML fragment is not even a full page and contains no query code.

I suggest you find out if your external database has a RESTful API available. You can then use App script to march through your spreadsheet and make queries on after another using that API.